# Conditionally select a column in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

say I have a table like this:

```
    table messages
id | show_message | message
 3 |   false      | "some message"
 4 |   true       |  "another message"
```

I want to only select the message column if `show_message` column is true, but I also want to select the show message column either way. Would a subquery be suitable in the scenario? I feel like I'm overthinking this. I'm using Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about a simple [case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)?

```
select id, show_message, (case when show_message then message end) as message
from t;
```

This will put a `NULL` value in the `message` column in the result set for messages that are not shown.

SQL queries return a fixed set of columns.  So, this is the best you can do with a single query.  If you really want a result set that sometimes has two columns and sometimes has three, then some sort of conditional logic or dynamic SQL would be needed.

Comment: returning the column as null is totally fine because I can check the value of show_message before trying to do anything with it. Never used case but it looks like exactly what will work for me. I will try it out.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: For anyone who wants to dig deeper - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-conditional.html